# interacting with an external django project from within another django project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm looking for a way to interact with the models of a django project from within a separate django project. I don't mean different apps, I mean 2 separate projects with 2 separate settings files.

I'm in the process of migrating an old web store (really old, it's all static html) to our django based backend. To do this, I created a separate django app that would handle all of the crawling and parsing, using the django orm and a few views for human assisted parsing. Now I'm at a point where I need to populate the catalog data of our backend with the data stored in the crawler project. I've spent the better part of the last 2 days trying to figure out a method, with no luck.

What I'd ideally like to do is import the store project as a module into a django command class and then interact with it that way (mind you, they are working off of 2 separate settings files, so setup_environ won't work). I'd like to avoid serializing the crawler data and then importing it from the store or interacting with the store database outside of django's orm because this project is far from over and I'd prefer to keep things as flexible as possible.

What would you suggest? I'm up for wild ideas, so long as I can interact with the orm of both projects from within a single script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this before...

So,

Project A, Project B

Project B wants to call models in Project A...

**1) Project B connects to the same database with the same user/login as Project A.**

If so then you can just import models from Project A into Project B and interact with them like normal.

**2) Project B connects to a different database than Project A.**

You can define two databases in the settings file for Project B.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
    },
    'users': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    }
}
```

And then either define a [db router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) so django knows what database to go to to get data for models from Project A

**OR**

You can explicity set the db to use when making calls the ORM using something like:

`Author.objects.using('other').all()`

Comment: How about two different projects that has thoroughly different apps within the project? How to make the call of ORM in project A from project B?

Answer (score -1):

Why not replicate the models from the crawler into your new project (so they are created in the same project space), then simply use django's manage.py to dump the data from the old crawler project into json files and migrate them over to your new project?

Provided your crawler project is settings/db type independent, you should be able to migrate your handlers/views/urls whatever you have to the new project and merge them together too?

If you keep the external models in sync in the new project, you will not have to do any extra work and you could use something like south app to migrate the data context.

That way you can simply import the old models in the new project and have them interact directly.

Otherwise, you are looking at message passing/network communication i.e. inter process communication.

Comment: If you're server is a *nix box, you could even just symlink the models from the old app into the new project. That way, they'd both _look_ like distinct models, but they'd use the same code so when one got updated, the other would as well.

Comment: Actually that's a great suggestion. I would just add that windows and mac both have symbolic links support. On Windows it's provided by NTFS through mklink and on Mac they are called aliases.

Comment: I've considered something like this, and the symlink idea is actually a great idea. However, it's something I'd like to avoid for a few reasons. Work / new data is ongoing with the crawler, so copying the tables from one project to the other will cause trouble. Additionally, migrating and updating data will be an iterative process that will require the crawler to keep track of what it's updated. So now we're talking about copying tables back and forth. Finally, it's not the end of the world, but all of the apps within the crawler share names with the store app.